# Travel to Canada and back by car

Tags: passports

We are traveling to Canada on 7/2/19. My 19 year old son did not get his passport (they screwed up twice). Is there any way he can still travel with us to Canada and back? We are traveling by car to Toronto from New York.

Comment: What country are you a citizen of?